# Can I set a property by the property name?

Tags: c#, mvvm, properties

Fairly new to wpf, using the galasoft mvvm templates.
I have two relaycommands that do the same thing, but they need to set different properties.

Can I do something like this?

```
public RelayCommand OpenDestinationCommand { get; private set; }
public RelayCommand OpenSourceCommand { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
{
    OpenSourceCommand = new RelayCommand(() => GetPath(SourcePathPropertyName));
    OpenDestinationCommand = new RelayCommand(() => GetPath(DestinationPathPropertyName));
}

private void GetPath(string PropertyName) {
    //show a dialog, get the path they select
    string newPath = GetPathFromDialog();
    //what should this look like? Is this possible?
    var Property = GetPropertyByName(PropertyName);
    Property.Set(newPath);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoulda googled first.
adapted from http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2006/11/19/97548.aspx

```
private PropertyInfo GetPropertyByName(string propName)
{
  return this.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
}

private void GetPath(string PropertyName) {
    //show a dialog, get the path they select
    string newPath = GetPathFromDialog();
    //what should this look like? Is this possible?
    var mProp = GetPropertyByName(PropertyName);
    mPropp.SetValue(this, newPath, null);
}
```

Comment: An aside: reflection is *comparatively* slow - it'll be fine as long as it isn't in a tight loop or hot path. If it is: there are faster options - let me know if you need this.

Comment: If you've got a better answer lemme have it! Don't spend too much time though, perf is definitely not an issue here.

Comment: I was mostly curious if there was something built in to wpf and/or mvvm light. I completely zoned in and forgot about reflection when I posted the question.

Comment: if perf isn't an issue you should be fine - however, maybe look for FastMember (on Nuget or Google Code)